# Bootstrap glyphicons error 404 in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I'm using bootstrap-sass-rails [this issue](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails/issues/62) and when I run my rails project in production mode I get 3x 404 errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 (Not Found) assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff:1
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not Found) assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf:1
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

I used rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production to generate static files with result :

```
I, [2013-11-07T16:52:25.269370 #12948]  INFO -- : Writing myproject/public/assets/application-3517eb39b597107b3dbccbcbf4f0b3cc.js
I, [2013-11-07T16:52:25.315358 #12948]  INFO -- : Writing myproject/public/assets/application-1459bfe79a6477170658d53257e4a8fd.css
I, [2013-11-07T16:52:25.334356 #12948]  INFO -- : Writing myproject/public/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-8b1bdc16b9e098d67afebbf8d59fcea7.eot
I, [2013-11-07T16:52:25.345360 #12948]  INFO -- : Writing myproject/public/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-8d8305e5b6a807076d3ec68e2f190674.svg
I, [2013-11-07T16:52:25.357360 #12948]  INFO -- : Writing myproject/public/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-946071b70245967633bb3a774c60f3a3.ttf
I, [2013-11-07T16:52:25.367360 #12948]  INFO -- : Writing myproject/public/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-d7e2274ad1d940a0b2ce7480810ab223.woff
etc ...
```

All assets are working fine except these 3 font files. I searched all day long and didn't find anything. It seems rails is looking for the version without hash of these 3 files but rake generates them with hash

my config/production.rb :

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

**EDIT**

I tried to override the @font-face variable but it doesn't seem to remove old variables:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: asset-url('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot',font);
  src: asset-url('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix',font) format('embedded-opentype'), asset-url('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff',font) format('woff'), asset-url('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf',font) format('truetype'), asset-url('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular',font) format('svg');
}
```

I now have glyphicons loaded but still 3x 404 errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok then.

I switched to https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass . 
Pretty same bootstrap version and no problem with it.

EDIT UPDATE

bootstrap-sass has been updated. You need to make some changes as explained on github page if you still have 404 errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I had to add `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` in addition to `@import "bootstrap"` inside `application.css.sass`.

Comment: Yep, as said in CHANGE LOGS if you don't install it for the first time, check out again the README page !

Answer (score 2):

ADD MIME TYPE into your webserver.

You have to define how to provide woff file.

for IIS, go to your IIS and open MINE type window

click ADD and type "**woff**" for first input box 
and "**application/x-font-woff**" for second box

then repeat for other extensions

good luck

Comment: Google brought me here and the downvoted IIS answer worked for me,  thanks, not using Ruby but the solution is valid

Answer (score 1):

the font directory is not automatically seen as a asset directory. You need to add it explicitly by setting: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")` in the `application.rb` file.

Comment: I dont' have fonts directory. bootstrap-sass-rails contains the fonts already, they're not in my project. Or I didn't understand what you're talking about.